ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage) Issue in Rails application
Error: The application encountered the following error: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in rescue in _decrypt' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:180:in _decrypt'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in decrypt_and_verify' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in decrypt_and_verify'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:91:in decrypt' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in read'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in read' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in config'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in options' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in method_missing'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/devise-4.9.4/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in key_exists?' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/devise-4.9.4/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in find'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/devise-4.9.4/lib/devise/rails.rb:41:in block in <class:Engine>' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in run' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in tsort_each' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in each_strongly_connected_component_from' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in each' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in each_strongly_connected_component' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in initialize!' App 194034 output:     /var/www/releases/20240625225657/app/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
App 194034 output:     config.ru:3:in require_relative' App 194034 output:     config.ru:3:in block in '
App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in instance_eval' App 194034 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in initialize'
App 194034 output:     config.ru:1:in new' App 194034 output:     config.ru:1:in '
App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in eval' App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in preload_app'
App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in block in <module:App>' App 194034 output:     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:399:in run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in <module:App>' App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in module:PhusionPassenger'
App 194034 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `'
[ E 2024-06-25 16:00:04.6168 181785/T5v age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/current/app: The application encountered the following error: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
Error ID: 89e085aa
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-1cXizv.html
[ E 2024-06-25 16:00:04.6189 181785/Tb age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:281 ]: [Client 2-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 89e085aa. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
I have below files
master.key
credentials.yml.enc
master.key created with rails credentials:edit
Also echo $RAILS_MASTER_KEY. is set with master key value
Rails version is  6.1.7.8
